# How to apply automatic versioning to a C# class

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am looking for a way to automatically version some of my C# classes. For example, consider I have a "Person" class that only contains properties for "Name" and "Email". Now, lets say that after a while I update this class definition so that "Person" also contains a property for "Age". If I make such a change I want to be able to automatically increment the version number of the class.

I want to use this functionality in a C# application where I save the specific class to MongoDB. MongoDB allows me to save a "Person" document to the "Person" collection regardless of the underlying attributes that make up a "Person". That is, if I write "Persons" to the database before I make my change, I will end up with "Person" documents that only contain a "Name" and an "Email". But any "Person" that I write after my class change will contain a "Name", "Email" and "Age". So I end up with documents in the same collection that can be different. I want to be able to save a value with each document indicating the "version" of the document/class, so that when I eventually query the database I am able to only query documents of a specific "version".

I can easily save a manual property at the class level and have a developer manually increment this if the class changes significantly, but this is error prone as someone might forget to update this value. I'd like to have it automatically generated. I was thinking that I could perhaps generate a hash code based on the class's set of properties (using reflection). This will guarantee that I get a unique value for the class that changes should any of the properties change. The problem with this approach is that the numbers I get will not be incremental (so I won't know which versions are older or newer) and it is also not very efficient.

Is there a way to automatically get a "version number" for a class that increments only when I make a change to the class?

(I should mention that the target .NET Framework is version 4.0)

Comment: I think there is no other way than doing this 'manual'. Versioning in .Net is based on the assembly, not individual classes within an assembly. You could have 1 class per assembly and version that way, but i wouldn't advise it since it will leave you with to many assemblies and decouple related classes.

Comment: **One step behind.** What's your goal with that? Do you try to manually develop a Source Control framework (with version history)? Solution depends on your target...

Comment: I think the problem is that you will end up hiding data, if the query needs to query a different collection then it should be stored as a different collection in mongo.
Or you need to run some kind of backdated update to make sure all the old objects have the new fields populated

Comment: @Adriano: No, I'm not doing a Source Control Framework. I just want to use it as a mechanism for knowing what data I might expect from my objects in the database. Eg, I may write a report that queries the database and requires data to be at a certain "version" (in the simplified example I post in my question, a report on "Age" would be nonsensical on "version 1" of the documents since they will not have an age.) (In the simplified example it seems easy to just include an "if statement" in report for when "Age" field is empty, but becomes complex in real-world scenario with many fields.)

Comment: What about a service layer? It'll provide data with requested version (and optionally can even do some _adapting_). Of course it has to be done through a post build step (BUT I would consider T4 to generate together both your classes - Person, for example - and this mapping layer). If done via T4 you may even use date as counter...

Comment: @g7876413: I don't wish to store the objects in a different collection as that would mean I have to create a new collection each time my class definition changes. Backdated updates are also not an option as such updates are very inefficient in MongoDB and in many cases I wouldn't be able to bring those "older versions" of documents up to date as I won't have the data available. Besides, even if I wanted to do a backdated update I would need to somehow know which documents to apply this update to, in which case if I had been able to save a version number with the document it would have helped.

Comment: I see, well mongo does expose an update method that will allow you to add a new field to a document and set a default value for it on mass (which is not as bad as one at a time)
If you have even some of the data then obviously i would recommend trying to load them, update, then save them as a one off deployment exercise.
When adding fields to mongo documents I find making them nullable will remove any errors in the re-hydration of the object, and removing fields is just a bit bad in general.
Sorry to not answer the question, but I think you may cause more problems with a versioning system.